# Launch browser intent without plugin support

Tags: android, plugins, browser

I'm writting an app that launches some custom URLs. Sometimes I want to have Flash support and somtimes not. In my opinion, the best way to do this is changing the share_pref "plugin_state" of the browser, but I don't know if it is possible to do from an external app.

¿Is there a way to activate/deactivate the plugin_state when launching the browser activity?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to activate/deactivate the plugin_state when launching the browser activity?

No, sorry. For starters, many Android browsers do not have "plugin_state". Second, the decision on whether or not to display Flash content is up to the user and their chosen browser, not you.

If you need that degree of control over the Web experience, embed a `WebView` widget in your application and figure out what bits of magic are needed to enable Flash support in it.

Comment: It is not for a normal mobile device app. It's a laucher for a TV device, so I need to decide if I display Flash content or not. And yes, we decide to implement our WebView because there is no way to do that :). Thank you!